# Harmonize width of MusiXTex extracts automatically

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, width, automation, musixtex

> *An answer which is sufficient but not optimal has been found. **Any improvements are welcome.***

Several `MusiXTeX` extracts are placed in a few floats as subfigures of a document. The width variation of these extracts within a figure environment might not please the eye. The widths do not vary much. So a uniform width might be beneficiary. Is there a way to achieve this automatically? If so then the width should adjust in each figure environment individually. Perhaps, it is reasonable to extend the question to harmonize the width of several extracts in different floats on the same page.

The following MWE shows the problem and my manual approach can be found in the answers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[narrow example]{%
\begin{music}%
\nobarnumbers%
\startextract%
\NOTEs\wh{cdefg}\enotes%
\endextract%
\end{music}}

\subfloat[wide example]{%
\begin{music}%
\nobarnumbers%
\startextract%
\NOTes\ha{cdef}\enotes\bar%
\NOTes\ha{ghi}\enotes%
\endextract%
\end{music}}

%\subfloat[test]{%from p. 116 of the manual, most like useless for this problem
%\begin{music}%
%\let\extractline\hbox
%\hbox to \hsize{%
%\hss\startextract\NOTes\hu{cd}\enotes\endextract\hss%
%\hss\startextract\NOTEs\wh{cd}\enotes\endextract\hss}%
%\end{music}
%}
\caption{Can these two examples automatically have the same width?}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark.** I apologise in advance for the bad pun in the title.

Comment: Harmonize "width"?  Okay: widpth

Comment: If my humor is not understood about harmonizing "width", then let me make it crystal clear: `wi\raisebox{-20pt}{\NOTes\ha{h}\enotes~~\,\NOTes\ha{i}\enotes~~}th`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Honestly, I do not really get it. Perhaps, I need to study the foundations of eye music. But I am happy that my disgraceful pun inspired you to a joke.

Comment: The joke is that the "d" in width looks like a half note.  The following "p" also looks like a harmonized half note with the "d".  Thus, 2 half notes in harmony..."widpth" is harmonized!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thank you. That makes sense. So you only introduced the "p"  or `\ha{i}` to force a "harmony" (two semitones, does that count as "harmonic"?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a manual approach, hence the question is answered *except for the automatic aspect.*

The use of `\hsize=\musicwidth` might be more natural and more efficient than a `\parbox` or `minipage` for encapsulation. Needless to say: A global non-changing definition of the width satisfies the requirement of constant width on the same page within several `figure` environments but might not be appropriate for all excerpts. However, a compromising size for most figures might exist.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,musixtex}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering%new

\subfloat[narrow example]{
%\fbox
{\begin{music}
\hsize=\musicwidth%new
\nobarnumbers%
\startpiece%new
\NOTEs\wh{cdefg}\enotes%
\endpiece%new
\end{music}}}

\subfloat[wide example]{
%\fbox
{\begin{music}
\hsize=\musicwidth%new
\nobarnumbers%
\startpiece%new
\NOTes\ha{cdef}\enotes\bar%
\NOTes\ha{ghi}\enotes%
\endpiece%new
\end{music}}}

\caption{This manual approach by try and error works. But there might be room for improvement.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark.** Perhaps the subtle comment in `\startpiece%new` needs additional explanation: In contrast to the MWE of [Harmonize width of MusiXTex extracts automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479943/128553), this proposal requires the generation of the `*.mx2` file as written in the manual  https://ctan.org/pkg/musixtex in the section "three pass system" (read the fine manual, RTFM).

Comment: I will delete my prior comments and, as they say, RTFM!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  A classic "read the fine manual" issue, indeed. Glad I could help you.

Comment: Voila!  Thank you for getting through to this hard head.